# How can I use Nunit with different class and TextFixtureSetup and TearDown

Tags: nunit

I have a big problem, i had 3 test class, but i create other to insert data fake in database to test my class, but i create other class to delete this data i was creating.

But i used **[SetUp]** in the class to create fake data and **[TearDown]** in the class to delete data.

But using **[SetUp]** or **[TestFixtureSetUp]** was creating the data two times and do a test but when i finish the class automatic class finish with the **teardown** or **TextFixtureTearDown** and don't start other tests this other test happens after **teardown**

Is it possible to write a class to fill the database with test data before running all my test fixtures and then have it delete test data after all of test classes run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question, I think you can use a common base class for your tests:

```
public class TestBase{
  [SetUp]
  public void BaseSetUp(){
     // Set up all the data you need for each test
  }

  [Teardown]
  public void BaseTeardown(){
     // clean up all the data for each test
  }
}

[TestFixture]
public class TestClass : TestBase{
  [SetUp]
  public void LocalSetUp(){
     // Set up all the data you need specifically for this class
  }

  [Teardown]
  public void LocalTeardown(){
     // clean up all specific data for this class
  }

  [Test]
  public void MyTest(){
        // Test something
  }

}
```

This way all your setup and teardown can be shared and will be run before EVERY test.  You can verify this (I'm doing this from memory), but I believe the running order will be:

- TestBase.BaseSetup()
- TestClass.LocalSetup()
- TestClass.MyTest()
- TestClass.LocalTeardown()
- TestBase.BaseTeardown()

**EDIT:**
Okay, now that I understand better what you're asking for, I think you can use the [SetupFixture](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=setupFixture&r=2.4) attribute to make sure your data setup and teardown only happens once for your full test suite.

So, instead of a common base class, you'd setup a separate setup class as follows:

```
   [SetupFixture]
   public class TestSetup{
      [SetUp]
      public void CommonSetUp(){
         // Set up all the data you need for each test
      }

      [TearDown]
      public void CommonTeardown(){
         // clean up all the data for each test
      }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class TestClass1 {
      [SetUp]
      public void LocalSetUp(){
         // Set up all the data you need specifically for this class
      }

      [Teardown]
      public void LocalTeardown(){
         // clean up all specific data for this class
      }

      [Test]
      public void MyTest(){
            // Test something
      }

    [TestFixture]
    public class TestClass2 {
      [SetUp]
      public void LocalSetUp(){
         // Set up all the data you need specifically for this class
      }

      [Teardown]
      public void LocalTeardown(){
         // clean up all specific data for this class
      }

      [Test]
      public void MyTest(){
            // Test something
      }

    }
```

Then the order of operations would be something like:

- TestSetup.CommonSetup()
- TestClass1.LocalSetup()
- TestClass1.MyTest()
- TestClass1.LocalTeardown()
- TestClass2.LocalSetup()
- TestClass2.MyTest()
- TestClass2.LocalTeardown()
- TestSetup.CommonTeardown()

**NOTE:** All of your tests must be in the same namespace.

Comment: is almost this Mike, i want to insert data in database once and start to do all test, when i finish all tests I will delete data in the database. but this form **setup** and **teardown** and inheritance in each test insert data in database and delete for each test. Do you now how do this?

Comment: In your base class use the FixtureSetup and FixtureTeardown attributes instead of what I previously suggested.

Comment: I made this, but every test class, it´s call again fixtureSetup and finish the class call teardown base. I want create once for all class and once teardown for all class, not one per class

Comment: I've added another solution to my answer - see my edit above.

Comment: That's great!  Please, mark the answer as accepted so future users know it's a good answer.